# Best practices to keep your ubuntu desktop and laptop in sync?

Tags: sync

How would you approach if you want your desktop and laptop to be in sync. So you don't have to install/configure the same app twice and also can just stop working on the one device and continue on the other?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you intent to do this? There are actually too many solutions that could work somehow for what you try to do. For example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40424/how-to-sync-two-directories

Answer (score 2):

OK. What you need is two separate features. I only know a lot about one, but I will do my best to give you the background to the other.

I have 8 computers in my house, and keeping all my files on all of them is a necessity. Unfortunately, I also have about 25 GB of files to sync, so I couldn't use any on-line storage site - they don't give you enough space (except for [copy.com](http://copy.com) - you can sign up for 2 free accounts, and share the data between them. It will be half on one, half on the other, so if you share everything you have 30 GB of space. Whether or not this is allowed, I don't know. It also means that your data is twice as likely to be hacked into.)
Anyway, another solution which doesn't require your files being stored on-line is [Bit torrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync). This requires a program to be installed on both computers (it's available for free on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux). You then enter a secure address (which it generates) and it syncs your files across - either via your LAN or the internet, and their servers.
You could also sync the folders with the program files in them, but that could cause instability. In the ubuntu software centre, you can sync installed programs to another computer.
Click on

`File -> Sync Between Computers`

You then sign up for an Ubuntu Software Centre account (which may be the same as an Ubuntu 1 account). On the second computer, you sign in to this account in the same way,

`File -> Sync Between Computers`

but then click 'I already have an account'

look at [this How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/111989/how-to-sync-quickly-reinstall-applications-on-ubuntu/) article for more information.

Comment: +1 but I'm wondering if 5 1/2 years later you have a new way of integrating your 8 computers?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix unfortunately (for this answer) I switched to macOS and now keep my devices in sync with iCloud. I think that the service Google Drive provides may offer this and there’s an application for Linux? Not sure.

Comment: BitTorrent Sync seems to be called Resilio Sync now